# Ubuntu 17.10 - Ultrawide 21:9 resolution on Wayland

Tags: intel-graphics, wayland, artwork

I am having problem with setting up my ultrawide LG monitor - 21:9 option (2560x1080) isn't shown within display preferences.

I had this problem on previous versions as well but I was able to resolve it through `xrandr` but since new Ubuntu comes with Wayland I am stuck with 1920x1080. I am not sure how to fix this.

My machine has no dedicated graphic card just Intel card on processor:

```
Intel® Core™ i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4
Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
```

Comment: Choose Xorg session at login, and your old method will work.

Comment: @SorenA, yes, but it is good to have a general solution for Wayland. I've the same LG, but I haven't tested 17.10 yet.

Comment: @SorenA, thanks. That worked!
pa4080 sure it would be great if we have solution for Wayland but for now it works with Xorg session.

Comment: @SorenA, Cockhootec Yahrabee, here is the possible answer for Wayland: https://askubuntu.com/a/973582/566421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose Xorg session at login, and your old method will work.
I currently don't know a solution that works with Wayland.