# 17.10 Display issue during boot.

Tags: display, gpu-driver

My display will be blank/black upon boot. I've removed the HDMI cable, initiated a boot, then plug the HDMI back in and it worked. wondering what everyone's thoughts are on how to rectify this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Could you give us a bit more information to go on like your graphics hardware, `dmesg` output, ...

Comment: Recently I bought a new TV and I experienced a similar issue when connect it with an old PC with builtin video card. I bought a new video card and the problem was 'solved'. About a month later I found the new video card works on 1920x1080@59, but by default the builtin VC works with @60 Hz. So you may [check whether this is the problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/973189/566421) and then you could [**follow this answer to add proper resolution@refresh-rate**](https://askubuntu.com/a/973582/566421), .