# How to disable wayland in 17.10 in gdm3 login screen

Tags: xorg, radeon, display-resolution, 17.10, wayland

I just installed ubuntu 17.10. 
I'm using a Ryzen 1200 CPU and an RX-560 GPU with a 2580x1080 60Hz monitor.

The monitor is connected to the GPU through an HDMI cable.

When I'm using the native monitor resolution of 2580x1080, in the wayland session, the screen makes these very weird glitches. The glitches look like a refresh rate issue, one that is fixed by v-sync, but they are very intense and on the whole screen. As soon as I change the resolution to a lower one the screen becomes normal.

In the x.org session I can use whatever resolution I want, everything works great.

The problem is that during the boot-loading screen (the one that says "ubuntu") and at the login screen I see the same glitches on the screen until I login.

Is the boot-loading-indicator using wayland? Can I make it use x.org/x11? The same for the login screen?

Comment: Apparently there is an issue with the [refresh rate on Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973180/eye-strain-after-using-ubuntu-for-some-time/973189#973189). You can try to generate a custom resolution as it is [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution/973582#973582).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wayland how to set a custom resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, change this line:

```
[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to

```
[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: or https://askubuntu.com/a/966323/248467

Comment: True, still answered here, so people having only this question find it easily. Btw. if you believe the question to be a duplicate of an existing question you should flag the question for that.

Answer (score 1):

When logging in you, when you select your username (account) from the login screen, a small gear will appear below the login box. Select the gear and select Ubuntu from Xorg. This is a quick and easy way to set this and also set it back.

Comment: This does not address the OP's question.  This sets your login session to use Xorg. But the OP asked how to disable Wayland in gdm3 login screen.