# Dual Monitor (2x Acer R271) with Geforce GT 555

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 17.10, display-resolution, vga

With my Schenker XMG A 501 I have a problem with my 2nd Screen in Dual Mode. It's the one which is plugged in via VGA.

I only get it work with resolution 640 x 480 instead of 1920 x 1080.
With my Samsung on Windows it works, so it has to be a setup problem...

Can you give me some advice on how to get it to work with my Ubuntu 17.10 (with 1920 x 1080)?

@EDIT:
the suggested solution was no help for my problem. :-(
What more informations do you need to get my problem fixed?
I am using the Nvidia 390.25 driver.

---

Sure...But in the meantime I installed my Ubuntu fresh and now i'm not using the nvidia driver any more...

---

Here is the `lspci` output:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [1558:1500]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106M [GeForce GT 555M] [10de:0dce] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer GF106M [GeForce GT 555M] [1558:1500]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

---

Here is the `xrandr` output:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3584 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.93 +
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 connected 640x480+2944+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       66.67*   59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       66.67    60.00    59.95    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-2 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
  1024x768 (0x43) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x44) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x45) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  640x480 (0x47) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

Comment: @close-voters, please note all suggestions in the proposed duplication are about `xrandr` but here is mentioned Ubuntu 17.10. Maybe some of the links in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/973189/566421) could be useful.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'` and `xrandr`? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question (see  above) Does someone has any further help?!? The duplicate link/marking was no help for me.Thanks in advance for your further assistance.