# Timer/screensaver app to impose regime for eyes?

Tags: 20.04, software-recommendation, settings, screensaver

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I would love to install a sort of screensaver or timer in order to impose periods of relax for my eyes. It should show a screensaver every period of time for 10 minutes.

For instance, if I start the system at 9:00, the app should impose a screensaver at 9:50 (every 50 minutes) and keep it for 10 minutes. Then rinse and repeat the routine at 10:50 etc. You get the idea. Is there any app to accomplish this task? I checked several "screensavers" but they are based on the concept of inactivity and lack this cyclic functionality. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eye strain after using Ubuntu for some time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973180/eye-strain-after-using-ubuntu-for-some-time)

Comment: Are you looking something like https://ostechnix.com/safeeyes-an-useful-linux-utility-that-prevents-eye-strain/

Comment: @nobody yeah, I am currently trying this out, very nice app

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own script that does that. Alternatively, you could use a tool like "Pomodoro" that is designed to remind you to take short breaks after a preset amount of time.